# Curl command is syntactically incorrect

Tags: curl, postman

I have tried importing curl command in postman but its giving type error.

```
curl -X POST -k foo:foosecret@localhost:9000/hascode/oauth/token \
   -d grant_type=password -d client_id=foo -d client_secret=abc123 \
   -d redirect_uri=https://www.hascode.com -d username=bar -d password=barsecret
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image: screenshots]

Comment: There are 2 \ in the content, looks like it is copied from somewhere else?

Comment: yes its copied , i dont have its proper knowledge. I have tried by removing 2 \ but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the curl command:

- `\` should be deleted. It's copied from somewhere else (as line break).
- HTTP protocol is missing, it should be `http://localhost:9000`.
- Multiple `-d` appears. Only one `-d` is needed.
- The data `https://www.hascode.com` is not encoded.

A working curl command that can be imported into postman would look like below (if your server accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type):

```
curl -X POST http://foo:foosecret@localhost:9000/hascode/oauth/token -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=foo&client_secret=abc123&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hascode.com&username=bar&password=barsecret'
```